# react-router withRouter and TypeScript Generics

Tags: typescript, react-router

**Code**:

```
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from "react-router";
import * as React from "react";

interface Props<T> {
    foo: T;
    children: (foo: T) => React.ReactNode;
}

function Component<T>(props: Props<T> & RouteComponentProps) {
    return props.children(props.foo);
}

export const Bar = withRouter(Component);
```

**Error**:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '<T>(props: Props<T> & RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>) => ReactNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Props<{}> & RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>>'.
  Type '<T>(props: Props<T> & RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>) => ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<Props<{}> & RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>>'.
    Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any> | null'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any> | null'.
```

How could I add router properties to Component preserving T?

Comment: I don't think passing in a function as children is supported by `withRouter`. Unless you meant some other children (not jsx children). Also preserving the generics will be an issue, without an extra type assertion (TS can't preserve type params when  going through a HOC)